# Issues getting betfair API-ng "app key" from the API visualizer. Error DSC-0035

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, betfair

I am new to Betfair API. And I am having difficulties getting the Betfair `App Key` from the Betfair Visualizer https://api-ng.betstores.com/account/.

Whenever I try the function **getDeveloperAppKeys** with the session Token that I got from the chrome cookie resources while logging into my account, I get DSC-0035 Error Msg i.e

> "Invalid Credentials".

I have read there have been some recent changes and updates to the Betfair API. And it might be causing these issues. Your Guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! I tried using the bet pro visualizer the next day and it worked perfectly. Got two keys in the right side column (delay, active). SO try to copy the "exact" API key. Sometimes the mistake can be "incorrect API key". Now It works!